# Change cPanel root password for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel, centos6

I was configuring cPanel in a Amazon EC2 CentOS server. I was able to reach the login screen of WHM by using https://ipaddress:2087. But I can't enter inside it. I tried all my root and other user passwords.

### Is there any different configurations like "/usr/libexec/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin root password" of Webmin, specific for cPanel?

**Or is there any recommended method to install cPanel?** I am ready to start other server and perform as CentOS needs fresh server. Also I have added the Elastic IP.

Answer (score 1):

There is no different configuration of cPanel for Amazon EC2 server. I will suggest you please try to login your server through SSH and try to disable cPHulk Brute Force Protection on your server with the following command. May be your account is blocked in cPHulk Brute Force Protection database and due to that you are getting this issues.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/cphulk_pam_ctl --disable
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter the command below in the linux terminal to update your root password incase you forgot

```
passwd
```

enter a non dictionary password
confirm the new password

use that password to login whm at https://ipaddress:2087